# How to recover a partition that I can not see as a drive but it exists?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

My hard drive has 3 partitions, C:\ has the Windows, 2 other partitions contain the data. I can see only one of these two partitions. Normally I can not see the other partition but when I use Harddisk recovery programs I see that partition. I also see that there is data in that partition. Can anybody tell me how can I recover that partition without formatting the partition because the data inside that partition is really important for me. I use EASEUSE Partition Master Home Edition. But I was unable to recover my partition with this application. Is there any other better application to recover my partition? Thanks in advance.

![In the following link you can find the screenshot of the program I am using.][1]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326226/how-to-recover-a-partition-that-i-can-not-see-as-a-drive-but-it-exists#comment14910104_11326226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a "hidden partition", quite common to some manufacturers laptops. In most cases, it contains stuff needed for recovery -- so in case your installation gets messed up, you can boot from some CD shipped with the laptop, start some "emergency system", and let it "recover/restore" your C: partition -- using the data on that hidden partition. I doubt you have any of your own data on it, it probably is nothing else but the said recovery partition.

If you insist on taking a look into it, you could use a Linux LiveCD (such as e.g. [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.org/)). Those start a Live system without touching your own installations, and you can investigate your hard disk (amongst others; you can do a lot more with them, e.g. getting a taste of Linux).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Once I reinstalled my Windows. During Installation I divided the drive into 3 partitions and labeled two of them as Data1 and Data2. I am sure the data inside is my own data. With the program I mentioned I can browse my data but can not open it. The other partition was C:\. After installation I couldn't see the partition with label Data1. Somehow it got hidden. Both partitions are Primary though.

Comment: If you are sure about that, and want to force it visible again, you might check with [this forumthread at Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9060522). The steps described there require Linux (not especially Ubuntu) -- but I already told you about the LiveCDs to run without installing Linux to your machine.